# Seemingly identical expressions, only one evaluates!

Tags: evaluation, hold

I am having difficulty using `NMaximize` with a user-defined function that involves `NSolve`. Stack Trace shows trouble at the evaluation of the expression shown at the top of the screenshot below (here's a [link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pd5cDfH6HaVSGLNroAaq_Rr5T38EKvOa/view?usp=sharing)). However, when I recreate this expression it works fine. Why does the first `NSolve` fail to evaluate? Is this why the `NMaximize` also fails? How can I avoid these problems?

[image]

Update 1: following @BobHanlon's hint to convert the cells into `InputForm` I can see that the first expression is within `HoldForm`. I copied this from the Stack Trace. Does this `HoldForm` automatically apply when `NMaximize` is used? How can I avoid it?

```
In[2]:= HoldForm[
NSolve[{0 == (0.5*A*R*t)/(1 + A) - R*\[Lambda], 
0 == (0.5*A*R*(1 - t))/(1 + A) - P*\[Lambda], 
0 == 0.4*P - (0.5*A*R)/(1 + A) - A*\[Lambda], 1 == A + P + R, 
0 < A, 0 < P, 0 < R} /. {t -> 0.5}]]

In[3]:= NSolve[{0 == (0.5*A*R*t)/(1 + A) - R*\[Lambda], 
0 == (0.5*A*R*(1 - t))/(1 + A) - P*\[Lambda], 
0 == 0.4*P - (0.5*A*R)/(1 + A) - A*\[Lambda], 1 == A + P + R, 
0 < A, 0 < P, 0 < R} /. {t -> 0.5}]
```

Update 2: I know that I can circumvent this problem using the following:

```
NMaximize[{\[Lambda], 0 == (0.5*A*R*t)/(1 + A) - R*\[Lambda], 
0 == (0.5*A*R*(1 - t))/(1 + A) - P*\[Lambda], 
0 == 0.4*P - (0.5*A*R)/(1 + A) - A*\[Lambda], 1 == A + P + R, 
0 < A, 0 < P, 0 < R}, {A, P, R, t, \[Lambda]}]
```

but this was rather slow (when later evaluated for numerous points) and I was hoping to speed things up. => Update 4: the speed actually got worse.

Update 3: Using `f[t_?NumericQ]` solves the problem. Thank you Bob Hanlon and everyone for your help! :)

Comment: The linked file is not open access. Convert your cells to `InputForm` and copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: @BobHanlon, Nasser Sorry, I just updated the permission. Could you try again, pls? I want to share the original file in case this has anything to do with hidden unicode characters, etc.

Comment: if it is exactly the same expression, then any funny characters will be in both. Did you try from clean Kernel? does it happen each time that only the second command works and not the first?

Comment: @Nasser, Yes, clean kernel, swapped expression order, etc. didn't help. Can you download the file now?

Comment: I downloaded your notebook and found the same behavior.  It's not the order, there's just something odd about the first cell.  When I enter it, the cursor is first large, then when I move right it becomes normal size.  Similar at the end.  Seems somehow defective.  Did you copy and paste that from somewhere?  Anyhow, it seems unrelated to your second problem, which can be solved by `Clear[f]` then using `f[t_?NumericQ]` to define `f`.

Comment: Convert your first cell to `InputForm` and you will see that it is wrapped in a `HoldForm`. It cannot evaluate. The definition of `f` should be `f[t_?NumericQ] := ...` then start your code with `Clear["Global`*"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon you are exactly right! Yes, using `?NumericQ` solves the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The equations can be solved exactly .

```
eqns = {0 == (0.5*A*R*t)/(1 + A) - R*λ, 
    0 == (0.5*A*R*(1 - t))/(1 + A) - P*λ, 
        0 == 0.4*P - (0.5*A*R)/(1 + A) - A*λ, 
        1 == A + P + R, 0 < A, 0 < P, 0 < R, 0 < t < 1} //
   Rationalize;

sol = Solve[eqns, {P, λ, R, A}, Reals] //
  FullSimplify[#, 0 < t < 1] &

{* {{P -> 1/8 (8 - 3 t - Sqrt[64 + t (-128 + 89 t)]), λ -> 
   1/20 (8 - 3 t - Sqrt[64 + t (-128 + 89 t)]), 
  R -> (t (-8 + 3 t + Sqrt[64 + t (-128 + 89 t)]))/(8 (-1 + t)), 
  A -> -((-5 t + Sqrt[64 + t (-128 + 89 t)])/(8 (-1 + t)))}} *)

f[t_] = λ /. sol

(* {1/20 (8 - 3 t - Sqrt[64 + t (-128 + 89 t)])} *)

{max, arg} = Maximize[f[t], t] // FullSimplify

(* {1/89 (26 - 8 Sqrt[5]), {t -> 1/89 (64 - 6 Sqrt[5])}} *)
```

These are approximately,

```
{max, arg} // N

(* {0.09114, {t -> 0.568355}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, this system can be solved exactly. But I am preparing for more complex systems for which exact solution solution will be more complicated or not exist.

Comment: You indicated that you wanted to speed it up; looking for an exact solution rather than numerically solving for every value is a primary means of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably know how it was introduced, but the `HoldForm` is holding up the first expression.

[image]

**Conclusion** It is not a bug.

Comment: Thank you! yes, that's the problem. I just copied the it from the Stack Trace, but I am not sure *why* it gets introduced.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your "but this was rather slow (when later evaluated for numerous points) and I was hoping to speed things up. => Update 4: the speed actually got worse."**

You can speed up, generating interpolation functions for A,P, lambda ..., which you evaluate only once. Therefore regard A as A[t] ..., diffentiate your equations and solve with NDSolve with known initial (starting) values (here at t==.5).

```
eqs = {0 == (0.5*A*R*t)/(1 + A) - R*\[Lambda], 
   0 == (0.5*A*R*(1 - t))/(1 + A) - P*\[Lambda], 
   0 == 0.4*P - (0.5*A*R)/(1 + A) - A*\[Lambda], 1 == A + P + R, 
   0 < A, 0 < P, 0 < R, 0 < t < 1};

sol = Flatten@Solve[eqs[[4]], R]
(*   {R -> 1 - A - P}   *)

eqs2 = eqs /. sol

eqs3 = eqs2[[1 ;; 3]] /. sol /. {A -> A[t], 
          P -> P[t], \[Lambda] -> \[Lambda][t]} // Simplify

deqs3 = D[eqs3, t] // Simplify

solt12 = Flatten@
   NSolve[eqs /. t -> 1/2, {P, \[Lambda], R, A}, Reals] // Quiet

ndsol = Flatten@
  NDSolve[Join[deqs3, 
    Thread[{A[.5], 
       P[.5], \[Lambda][.5]} == ({A, P, \[Lambda]} /. solt12)]], {A, 
    P, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

Plot[Evaluate[{A[t], P[t], 1 - A[t] - P[t], \[Lambda][t]} /. 
   ndsol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue}]

NMaximize[{\[Lambda][t] /. ndsol, 0 < t < 1}, t]

(*   {0.09114, {t -> 0.568357}}   *)

NMaximize[{P[t] /. ndsol, 0 < t < 1}, t]

(*   {0.22785, {t -> 0.568357}}   *)
```